# Xamarin - No resource found that match

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently reinstalled Xamarin after the install of Win10 on my computer.

As always, installing Xamarin and launching a basic Xamarin.Forms app won't work, you need to get some troubles and here are mine :

> No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionModeOverlay'.
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.

I've read several topics that said you need to change the min SDK version to this:

`<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" android:minSdkVersion="23" />`
and have all packets up to date in Android SDK Manager (it's the case too).

But I still get the errors.

Any hint what to change in order to get my basic app working?

**EDIT**
styles.xml exists and looks like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   [...]
```

Comment: During my work with Xamarin I have experienced lots of "no reason" errors. At first I was trying to solve them  on my own (checking Xamarin forums, google) but eventually REINSTALLATION solved them all.

Comment: I already reinstalled Xamarin...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, got it after many tries, so what to do:

Visual Studio:

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings` : Change to JDK 1.8 (instead of 1.7) !
2. Close VS

> Changing to JDK 1.8 will permanently avoid the error `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

Windows (Local):

2. Delete all `Xamarin.Android.*` folders in `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Xamarin`
3. Delete the `zips` folder in the same location

Windows (in my project folder):

3. Delete `.vs` folder
4. Delete all `Xamarin.Android.*` folders in `packages` folder
5. Delete `/obj` and `/bin` folder in the .Droid project

Reopen Visual Studio and rebuild your solution.

On first compile, be patient! Zips are downloaded again in `Xamarin/zips` and extracted (take at least 5 minutes on my computer).

Wait ...
Wait ...

And it's okay, solution is deployed on my smartphone and everything works fine.
Thanks to all.

Hope it will help someone else!

Comment: That helped. Thanks.

Comment: I just performed the project folder steps and this solved my issue.

Comment: All I needed to do was delete obj and bin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

i had this issue when i copied the project to another directory

i resolved it by deleting the `.vs` folder and `project.sln.dotsettings.user` file and deleted `obj` and `bin` folder in `.android` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin is great - but that issues are annoying. Please try this:

First solution:
 - Remove and install again the following library `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`

Second solution:

- Close VS
- Delete all bin & obj folders in all projects
- Delete everything in packages folder
- Delete everything in C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin (Except for mono & android)
- Open the solutin and rebuild. It should download again all the required libraries.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2017:

Go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings:

Checked the Checkbox **Auto Install Android SDKs**  then click OK button

Closed Visual Studio and open again

Answer (score 0):

I simply just did a right click on the Droid project and clicked "Clean". Once I did that my builds and deploys were working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Update Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat to newest version did fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a fixed for me by updating my NuGet Packages.

Directions:
1) Click Project in the menu bar.
2) Select Update NuGet Packages.
3) Rebuild Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed **I**nterviewer_main_drawer.xml to **i**nterviewer_main_drawer.xml and everything worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

That variables you talk about:

```
windowNoTitle, windowActionBar, colorPrimary...
```

Are defined at Resources/values/styles.xml and/or Resources/values-v21/styles.xml if you work with API > 21 (Android 5.0)

Try to change it for:

```
android:windowNoTitle, android:windowActionBar, android:colorPrimary
```

If you are using themes from Resources/values/styles.xml but you are working with API > 21 you need to add that `android:` prefix in order to reference that values correctly.

Comment: Thanks but the question was posted 4y ago (in 2017), I have found the solution since