# Resource not found error in VS Xamarin App after Nuget updates

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I wrote an App that has been working for several years. Today, regretfully, I updated the Nuget packages and now I get the errors shown below.
I installed the latest Android SDKs (Android API 32, Platform 33) but it did not change anything.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. i don't want to retire this great app.

Error       failed linking references.  MyApp.Android
Error       resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka MyName.MyApp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.  MyApp.Android
Error       resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka MyName.MyApp:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.    MyApp.Android
Error       style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found. MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   2
Error       style attribute 'attr/windowNoTitle (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/windowNoTitle)' not found.   MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   2
Error       style attribute 'attr/windowActionBar (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/windowActionBar)' not found.   MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   2
Error       style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/colorPrimary)' not found. MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   2
Error       style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/colorAccent)' not found.   MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   3
Error       style attribute 'attr/windowActionModeOverlay (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/windowActionModeOverlay)' not found.   MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   4
Error       style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka MyName.MyApp:attr/colorAccent)' not found.   MyApp.Android   Location\App1.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml   4

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Fast ways is to delete obj and bin file.

**Solution 2**

You can try the method provided by Arnaud F. in this case: [Xamarin - No resource found that match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42402252/19902734).

Comment: The proposed solutions did not seem to work for me. in fact, there are now more errors.
it seems that i am missing at least one library: 
global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity:The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform'  
Am I missing some Nugetrs now? if so which?

Comment: Do you have `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat` package?

Comment: It seems that whatever i did yesterday wiped out all the NuGet packages, there were none installed. i added it but am still getting errors. What other packages should i add?

Comment: `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` ? In addition, if the original project is not large, I recommend building a new project and migrating the code. I understand that reporting errors during updates and upgrades of old projects can be quite frustrating:(

Comment: last question?
the main error is 
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
on this line in MainActivity.cs, a class that VS created.

  [Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
  public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity

Xamarin.Forms is included in the references. which library would be missing?

Comment: About this error: CS0234(The type or namespace name 'Android'....) you can refer to these two cases: [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591881/xamarin-forms-platform-android-does-not-exist-after-xamarin-update-from-2-5-to-3), [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510688/error-cs0234the-type-or-namespace-name-android-does-not-exist-in-the-namespac).